# not able to display controls add in scroll view's content view using auto layout

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I am new in auto layout part. I am creating one view with scroll programatically but I am not able to add controls in the content view of scroll view

Here is my code:

```
-(void)setConstraints
{

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
    [scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIView *contentView = [UIView new];
    [contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *lableTitle = [UILabel new];
    lableTitle.text = @"Registration";
    [lableTitle setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSLayoutConstraint *layoutLableTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lableTitle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:20];
    [self.view  addConstraint:layoutLableTop];

    NSLayoutConstraint *layoutLableCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lableTitle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:layoutLableCenterX];

    [contentView  addSubview:lableTitle];
    [scrollView addSubview:contentView];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];


}
```

the view that is display is just white screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add constraints for sizes for example

```
[self.view addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:contentView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:200]];
[self.view addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:contentView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:200]];
```

Comment: Sorry @jaba but it display the view.

Comment: Where do you call the method?

Comment: it should display green view with 300-300 size.

Comment: yes it is displaying scrollview now @jaba. but still I have to do few more things. after that I 'll update you. If I am not able to find way.